# Tensorflow: error when computing gradients for complex variables

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, complex-numbers

I am trying to compute the gradients of a complex function in Tensorflow, but I have some trouble.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
def CompSEQ(seq, rho0):
    def EvolveRHO(prev, input):
        return tf.mul(tf.complex(input,0.0),tf.matmul(rho0,prev))
    def ComputeP(p, rho):
        return p * tf.real(tf.trace(rho))
    rhos = tf.scan(EvolveRHO, seq, initializer=rho0)
    p = tf.scan(ComputeP, rhos, initializer=tf.constant(1.0))
    return tf.gather(p,[tf.size(seq)-1])[0]
N = 4
seq = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[5])
x = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2*N*N], dtype=tf.float32))
seqP = CompSEQ(seq, tf.complex(tf.reshape(x[0:N*N],[N,N]),
                                tf.reshape(x[N*N:2*N*N],[N,N])))
#seqPp = tf.gradients([seqP], [x])  # THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM!!!
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
v = np.random.rand(2*N*N).astype(np.float32)
s0 = np.random.rand(5).astype(np.float32)
p = sess.run(seqP, feed_dict={seq:s0, x:v})
print('seqP',p);
```

I use an input float32 vector x that will be transformed into a complex matrix. All the computations are performed using complex numbers and the last tf.scan in the CompSEQ function transforms all the results into float32 by taking the real part.
If I comment the call to tf.gradients (as in the code) everything works fine, but when I try to compute the gradients I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "error.1.py", line 24, in <module>
    seqPp = tf.gradients([seqP], [x])   # THIS LINE CAUSES THE PROBLEM!!!
  File "/Users/tamburin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 486, in gradients
    _VerifyGeneratedGradients(in_grads, op)
  File "/Users/tamburin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py", line 264, in _VerifyGeneratedGradients
    dtypes.as_dtype(inp.dtype).name))
ValueError: Gradient type float32 generated for op name: "scan/while/Switch_1"
op: "Switch"
input: "scan/while/Merge_1"
input: "scan/while/LoopCond"
attr {
  key: "T"
  value {
    type: DT_COMPLEX64
  }
}
attr {
  key: "_class"
  value {
    list {
      s: "loc:@scan/while/Merge_1"
    }
  }
}
 does not match input type complex64
```

Converting all the computations into float32 variables resolves the problem, but I need to maintain the computation on complex variables (this is a simplified example w.r.t. my real problem).

Comment: Complex computation has some spotty support, it might be worth getting a smallest reproducible case, and filing an issue, and mentioning @ibab (he implemented a bunch of complex support recently)

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Could you link to issue